# Planting Seeds from Sweet Acacia

Tags: seeds

Super newbie here.  There are trees in my area which is Phoenix, that grow tiny yellow pom-poms.  Google tells me the tree is Sweet Acacia.  These trees are amazing to me!!!  I looked up how to plant from seed.
I picked up some seed pods that look like black, dried up beans.  I cracked them open to get to little black seeds that look like tics.  And Google further told me to put these seeds in near-boiling water and leave for 12 hours.  And then immediately put them into potting soil where they may sprout in 3-4 weeks. Am I on the right track?  The near-boiling water has me concerned.  How do these plants propagate naturally? If I follow the instructions above, can I expect the seeds to sprout?  Many thanks to anyone that can help.

Comment: Newbie here too. I've heard of, and applied the hot water method myself. I still haven't had any success with tree seeds -- they seem to be a real challenge to sprout. I suspect the hot water is an attempt to simulate conditions you might not have in your local climate, but I'm really not sure.

Answer (score 1):

4/10/21 Update: I followed instructions from Google to get water near boiling.  And then put the seeds in that water and left for 12 hours.  Next, I put the seeds into a wine glass, the only clear container I had, so I could check their progress. I pushed the seeds up to the side with some wet paper towels expecting nothing (the near-boiling water is not damaging the seeds?) BUT a few days later, the little buggers are actually germinating!  Now what.  I put some in potting soil with small rocks beneath hoping to keep them hydrated but not allowing root rot.  I hope they're ok.  Hoping I didn't harm them in this transfer.  I just really want a Sweet Acacia that I grew from seed :)  The yellow pom-poms they grow are so amazing to me.  And I must have one of those trees I grew from scratch.  This is not an answer but StackExchange won't let me post anything else.

4/13/21 Update: They're sprouting.  I'm still worried about root-rot.  I really am clucking over them like a mother hen.  Hoping they grow true leaves and then I will transport them to a bigger pot and then to the great outdoors.

4/17/21 Update: I have seedlings.  They are slowly growing tiny, adorable leaves. They are doing ok but I am very concerned about watering them correctly.  I have killed plants in the past with too much love.  I dug into the dirt to see if water is collecting near the bottom - so far all is well.  Next up is to find out what fish-fertilizer or compost-tea is because that is what Google tells me they need at some point.

4/18/21 Update: starting to thin the seedlings.  I gave them more water yesterday and let the pot drain well.  Keeping a close eye on them.

4/20/21 Update: they seem to be doing ok.  I see a few true leaves sprouting.  I thin them on occasion and the sprouts I pick have an odor - like oh no, root rot.  It wouldn't be the first time I killed a plant with that.  And I feel bad every time.  Are they warm enough?  I keep my place on the cool side but not freezing.  Do they have too much water or not enough.  On one of my recent walks I picked up a few more pods in case I kill the seedlings I have now.  Live.  Learn.  Hoping for the best!

Comment: Please consider [merging your unregistered and registered accounts](/help/merging-accounts), which will allow you to [edit](/help/privileges/create-posts), [comment on](/help/privileges/comment) any of your posts and most importantly [accept an answer](/help/someone-answers) on your question. Thanks, and welcome to the site!